# control structure

Tags: scala

Finding difficult understanding following control structure

```
scala> def twice(op: Double => Double, x: Double) = op(op(x))

twice: (op: (Double) => Double,x: Double)Double

scala> twice( _ + 1,5)

res0: Double = 7.0
```

Comment: Hmm. Your question is not very precise. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: That's a funny one because of the formatting, at least for people accustomed to ',' as decimal separator. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
op: Double => Double
```

is a function that takes a `Double` and returns a `Double` as a result.  `twice` is a method takes a number, calls `op` on it, and then calls `op` on the result.

```
_ + 1
```

is a function that takes a value and adds one to it.

You can probably figure out the rest from there.

Comment: Maybe my brain wasn't working..got confused w.r.t placeholder..but got it now...Thanks